# Objective C - Category to modify a singleton object?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, singleton, categories

I know that the whole point of singleton is to instantiate 1 instance of the onject and reuse it, but when it comes to unit testing I want to be able to renew the singleton object before every test.

I tried to use a category to access the singleton object and release it but It's not accessible by categories any idea what's the best way to achieve this?

```
@implementation SingletonClass

static SingletonClass *singleton;

+ (SingletonClass*)sharedInstance
{
   if (!singleton)
   {
      singleton = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
   }
   return singleton;
}

@end
```

.

```
@implementation SingletonClass(Unit Testing Additions)

+ (void)killInstance
{
   // I get an error here and I cannot access the singleton Object
   [singleton release], singleton = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Just a heads up, even if you were to try calling `release` on self, it won't work as singletons override `-release` by convention. I suppose you could override `-release` yourself in the category...

Comment: Don't use the word "class" in a class name.

Comment: “when it comes to unit testing I want to be able to renew the singleton object before every test.” This is one of the arguments against singletons. Does this object really need to be a singleton in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this will work, but maybe you could just override the `sharedInstance` class method and manage the singleton yourself:

```
@implementation SingletonClass (Unit Testing Additions)

static SingletonClass *myVeryOwnSharedInstance;

+ (SingletonClass *) sharedInstance
{
    if (!myVeryOwnSharedInstance)
        myVeryOwnSharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    return myVeryOwnSharedInstance;
}

+ (void) killInstance
{
    [myVeryOwnSharedInstance release];
    // if release is overridden to do no-op, maybe just invoke -dealloc directly
    myVeryOwnSharedInstance = nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

By the very definition of singleton, you can't do this.

If it is your class, don't make it a singleton.

If it isn't your class, doing this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to your `singleton` global variable outside of the file in which it's declared, you'll need to make it globally accessible using `extern`.

At the top of `SingletonClass.h`, put this:

```
extern SingletonClass *singletonClassSingleton;
```

In your `SingletonClass.m`, use this:

```
SingletonClass *singletonClassSingleton = nil;
```

Then assuming you have `#import "SingletonClass.h"` in your unit test .m file, you should be able to add:

```
@implementation SingletonClass(Unit Testing Additions)

+ (void)killInstance
{
   [singletonClassSingleton release], singletonClassSingleton = nil;
}

@end
```

The reason I've renamed `singleton` to `singletonClassSingleton` is that the variable is now global - if you have a bunch of singleton classes, you need these variables to have unique names, like `dataManagerSingleton`, `resourceManagerSingleton` or whatever.

Comment: I think the OP can't actually change the declaration of the singleton or even modify the original source code, otherwise this whole question is incredibly trivial (may as well put the `+killInstance` method into the class itself).

Comment: I thought that the OP was asking since they wanted to keep their tests in a separate file to the class itself. I can't see the OP stating that they don't have access to or the ability to modify the original source?

Comment: The class is accessible by me, I don't want to add killInstance to the actual class, that's horrible and it's against singleton pattern, The category belongs only to my test target, so I can only kill the singleton in my test target. I do not want anyone to be able to release or modify the singleton in my main target in any possible way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution.

```
@implementation SingletonClass(Unit Testing Additions)

//Override
static SingletonClass *singleton;

+ (void)killInstance
{
   // I get an error here and I cannot access the singleton Object
   [singleton release], singleton = nil;
}

//Override
+ (SingletonClass*)sharedInstance
{
   if (!singleton)
   {
      singleton = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
   }
   return singleton;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is identical to the answer by @dreamlax from a few days before!